# Sinatra config.ru loaderror

Tags: heroku, sinatra, datamapper

I've wanted to have a look at Sinatra after a long hiatus so I looked for a boilerplate to get it up on running on heroku quickly and found this > https://github.com/froots/sinatra-heroku-boilerplate

It seems to have everything I would need so I did *bundle install*, but whenever I fire up shotgun I'm running into this error:

```
Something went wrong while loading config.ru

NameError: uninitialized constant Object::DataMapper
```

Answer (score 2):

In the Gemfile, line 5 - it should be `gem 'data_mapper'`, not `gem "datamapper", ">=1.1.0"`

Once you've updated the gemfile, do another `bundle install`

**Update:**

I've submitted a pull request for the author to fix his code: https://github.com/froots/sinatra-heroku-boilerplate/pull/2